# ignoreCase sorting is not working on column

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In Jqgrid my column is as below,

```
{name : 'name',editable:true,width:120,sorttype:'string'},
```

but it provides case sensitive sorting as below.

```
- product Sales Agent
- email Queue
- default Queue
- Trouble Ticket
- Billing & Payment
```

I tried with ignoreCase:true also but it does not work.
I need sorting to be done by ignoring case as shown below,

```
- Trouble Ticket 
- product Sales Agent 
- email Queue 
- default Queue 
- Billing & Payment
```

Any idea how this can be possible ?

```
            colNames:['questionId','Name','Answer','Show','Edit','Option'],
            colModel : [
                {name : 'questionId',sorttype:'int',align:'left',editable:true, hidden:true},
                {name : 'name',editable:true,width:120,sorttype:'text',ignoreCase:true,soratble:true},                  {name : 'answer',align:'left',width : 400,sorttype:'string',editable:true},
                {name : 'enable',align:'center',width : 60,sorttype:'string',editable:true, formatter : formatEnable},
                {name : 'edit',editable:false, formatter:addEditButton,align:'center',width:50},
                {name : 'feedbackOptions.optionId',editable:false, align:'center', hidden:true},

            ],
            jsonReader : {root: "rows",
                  page: "page",
                  total: "total",
                  records: "records",
                  repeatitems: false
            },      
            multiselect : true,
            height: '170px',
            paging : true,
            emptyrecords : "<spring:message code='label.norecords'/>",
            viewrecords : true,
            rowNum : 10,
            rowList : [10,20,30],
            pager : "#pager",
            loadonce : true,                
            footerrow : false,
            userDataOnFooter : true,
            altRows : true,
            loadonce:true,
            loadComplete: function (data) {
                $('#buttonDiv').show();
              }
            }); 
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid("navGrid","#pager",{del:false,add:false,edit:false, search:false, refresh:false});
            },
            error:function(xhr,ajaxoptions,thrownError){

            }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Do you really need Java for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `sorttype:'string'` in `sorttype:'text'`.

Comment: Try to delete any attribute sorttype. Leave it only in one column. I think that take the first attribute that meets.

Answer (score 0):

Add `IgnoreCase: true` to the options of jqgrid instead of the column.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using 3.8 version of jqGrid. try to change as follows on grid.base.js

Make _usecase field to false and try.

from : function(source){
  ....
 _usecase=false,
}

The same issue been resolve on the later version hence no need to change over there.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I dropped here by accident while working. How if you try in your column like this?

Your column right now (or wherever the question was written):

```
{name : 'name',editable:true,width:120,sorttype:'text',ignoreCase:true,sortable:true}
```

The column with ignoreCase function using some JS trick:

```
{name:'name', editable:true, width:120, sortable:true, sorttype: function(cell,obj){
    return cell.toLowerCase()}
};
```

Notice `cell` contains the String value of the cell, so you have to work with that when you want to order the elements inside the jqGrid.

Hope it helps